# Powershell function acting weird and only returns the param

Tags: powershell

[context] I'm writing an application that converts xml data to Excel, the problem is that the excel file cant have empty entry's, but the xml has. My solution is that I created timestamps that I expected to see in the XML. The function below takes care of that. He's checking if the node exists and he's checking if the expected timestamp is there.

The weird thing here is that if I want to get my return values, I only see the parameters I gave.

This is my function

```
function CompleteData([array]$timestamps, [array]$measurements, [xml]$xml, [int]$aantalapplicaties, [array]$datesofthemonth) {
$indexgecontroleerd = 0
for ($i = 0; $i -le $aantalapplicaties - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j -le $datesofthemonth.Length - 1; $j++) {
        $indexgecontroleerd++
        $node = $xml.dashboardreport.data.chartdashlet[$j]
        if (!$node.measures.measure.measure.measurement[$j] -or $node.measures.measure.measure.measurement[$j].timestamp -ne $datesofthemonth ) {

            $correctTimestamps = $timestamps[0..$indexgecontroleerd - 1]
            $restTimestamps = $timestamps[$indexgecontroleerd..$timestamps.Length]
            $correctTimestamps += $datesofthemonth[$j]
            $timestamps = $correctTimestamps + $restTimestamps                
            $correctemeasurements = $measurements[0..$indexgecontroleerd - 1]
            $restmeasuremetns = $measurements[$indexgecontroleerd..$measurements.Length]
            $correctemeasurements += "0"
            $measurements = $correctemeasurements + $restmeasuremetns  
        }
    }
}
return $measurements, $timestamps
}
```

It's comming from 3 different XML's so here you have the reference to the function:

```
$return1 = CompleteData($timestamps1, $firstRowMesOG, $xdoc, $applicationArray.Length, $allDates)
$return2 = CompleteData($timestamps2, $betweenMesOG, $xdoc2, $applicationArray.Length, $allDates)
$return3 = CompleteData($timestamps3, $LastmesOG, $xdoc3, $applicationArray.Length, $allDates)
```

And this is what i get as return value:

```
PS C:\Users\yniasr> $return3


Length         : 184
LongLength     : 184
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {1517439600, 1517526000, 1517612400, 1517698800...}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 184

Length         : 184
LongLength     : 184
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {840, 718, 106, 6...}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 184

xml             : version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"
dashboardreport : dashboardreport

8
Length         : 28
LongLength     : 28
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {1517443200, 1517529600, 1517616000, 1517702400...}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 28
```

Where is my mistake? Still pretty new to powershell (version 5.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling powershell functions doesn't use parentheses and commas.  Your calls should look more like this:

```
$return1 = CompleteData -timestamps  $timestamps1 -measurements $firstRowMesOG -xml $xdoc -aantalapplicaties $applicationArray.Length -datesofthemonth $allDates
```